# How to type a generic change handler with keof?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

In many of my react forms I want to use a generic form change handler that can handle updating the different fields of a state object.

How do I correctly type this change handler so that the below invocations are resulting in a compile error:

```
interface Data {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

let data: Data = {a: "a", b: 1};

function changeHandler<T>(field: keyof Data, value: T) {
    data = {...data, [field]: value}
}

// should compile
changeHandler("a", "aa");
changeHandler("b", 11);

// should not compile
changeHandler("a", 1);
changeHandler("b", "b");

console.log(data);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGSOTgC5kBnMKUAcwG4DjkAjckAVwFsXpH8AvgQIAbCGGQATDGTQzkAXhyyARHBUAaVuQCMA-gRgcQCMMAD2IZAgAWcELQgAJe5LFQAPABUAfAAoYYAgRSXIAawgAT3MYOUwtADc4EQ4Ici8AShwmYmlMRRwAOmK8uC0AbUDgyQBdciSUiCFBYXwAejbKG3MOEOtzLgAHYDECW3tHFxA3aD81TWQ1dQz%20cYdnV3c5lgWdHRXWjq6evpBzCQQB4dH8NcnN2fmtfdW7damZqG2FlR2D-DGlgo5jEhRE5loflK-yAA)

The example is simplified and in the real application `React.useState` is used instead of using a `let` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding a generic parameter for the value, add it for the key, and by using [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) get the correct type for the value:

```
function changeHandler<T extends keyof Data>(field: T, value: Data[T]) {
  data = {...data, [field]: value}
}
```

Testing:

```
changeHandler("a", "aa"); // no error
changeHandler("b", 11); // no error

changeHandler("a", 1); // error
changeHandler("b", "b"); // error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5OALmQGcwpQBzAbn2QCMSQBXAWwejoF9dcAbCGGQATDMTTjkAXhwSARHHkAaRiQCM3OrhgsQCMMAD2IZAgAWcEFQgAJKyMFQAPABVkEAB6QQI0sgBrCABPIxhJTAA+AAoYYAh+ERJXVQA3OH4WCBJ0TABtVwBdAEocejFMGRwAOlqKuFU8uISRQpJ0zIheXlwLKxt7XydoxRVkRSVimmQAehnkECMPKCgjKF7LazsHYfkGMfV1Kdn5xeXV9Y3+7aHoEaVVI+m587WrrcHHO72xn+OX6AXPgIEykIyCar8IxUaL1YpAA)